# The following classes could not be found: - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayou

Tags: java, android, layout, constraints

I just had to move my android application to androidx because of several problems. Now I have the problem, that the App is "greyed out" in the Desginer (See Screenshot):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MEVR.png)

In the designer there is a error message:

```
    The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

I would assume there is a missing class for the constraint Layout, but that is not the case. That is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Do you have any idea?
I already tried everything on the internet, make app, rebuild, sync with gradle files, trying different versions of the constraint layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use AndroidX libraries and Support libraries in same project. Migrate to AndroidX from menu, it will replace package names and dependencies.

Your project is adding widgets from Support libraries instead of AndroidX which is causing this issue.

[image]

If you still get errors, replace old package names from the ones in the list: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked additionally I had to add androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout in my xml file :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` while adding a dependency to `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout`. Just use the latter in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the material design dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

your appcompat should also be:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

you are using androidx constaint layout dependency but your other dependencies aren't compatible